# Is Ruby 1.9.2 EOL?

Tags: ruby

Last patch version of Ruby 1.9.2 (p320) was released in April 2012, almost a year ago. Since then, 4 patch versions for 1.9.3 were released. Latest 1.9.2 version doesn't contain 1.9.3's security fixes: [fix1](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/11/09/ruby19-hashdos-cve-2012-5371/), [fix2](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/22/json-dos-cve-2013-0269/), [fix3](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/22/rexml-dos-2013-02-22/)

Is 1.9.2 still supported? Does it make sense to support MRI 1.9.2 in gems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Matz](https://twitter.com/yukihiro_matz/status/421152831844806656):

"1.8.7 and 1.9.2 EOL will be June 2014. 2.0 and 2.1 will be maintained for 2 years after the releases, under the current plan."

[According to the ruby issue tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9217) Zachary Scott says:

"1.9.3 will be EOL'd in March 2014 We will announce it officially with the announcement of 2.1.0 release. Additional 1.9.3 maintenance is depending upon Ruby Association contract extension with usa."

### my thoughts

- 1.9.3 ending before 1.9.2 is a little odd, but I suspect the install-base for 1.9.2 is a little larger.
- It would be nice if ruby-lang.org had a central table of latest ruby versions along with EOL.  Right now the information is a little scattered between submits, tweets, etc.  But  core team is very responsive.
- Given Heroku's support of Ruby, [looking at Heroku's supported Ruby versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions) may also give an indirect idea of support.

### update

The [Ruby Release Engineering](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering) page lists the following dates:

- Normal maintenance: finished on June 2012
- Security fixes: finished on 2013-06-01
- Extended maintenance: finished on 2014-06-30

### additional sources

- https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering

Answer (score -2):

I think latest supported version on 1.9 branch is 1.9.3. so if you are planning to support ruby 1.9 in your gems you should support 1.9.3.

for ruby 1.9 you will mostly find users using 1.9.3 since its the supported version for 1.9 branch. Also the language difference between 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 is minimal (1.9.3 is mostly work on a 'better implementation').

If you really want to support 1.9.2, then you should.

Comment: Sure, I should support 1.9.3. The question is whether I should support 1.9.2

Comment: I updated my answer. by supporting 1.9.3 you will be supporting 1.9.2 mostly (implicitly).